# open js file while click on the text

Tags: javascript, execute

I've got the problem.
I need to open the js file while clicking on text which.

I've got:

```
<script src="http://www.domain.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And when I click the image which appears the js script is executed and im rediredted to `http://www.domain.com/`.

so

clicked on js -> js script executed -> redirected to url(its scripted in js file to make it)

---

**Now I want to make it want to do it without image only with text**

so

clicked on text -> js script executed from `http://www.domain.com/file.js` -> redirected.

---

I tried to do it like:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/file.js">text</a>
```

but it not working propertly:

clicked on text -> redirected to `http://www.domain.com/file.js` adress -> clicked to execute js -> redirected

---

Please help me.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking.  Are you trying to execute some JavaScript code when clicking on a link?  When clicking on an image?  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
    <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
    <head>
 <title>YOUR_SITE</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a id='test' href="#">text</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#test').live('click', function() 
{
     $.getScript('your_script_file.js', function() {
alert('Load was performed.');
     });

}); 

});
```

link for jquery http://jquery.com/

Comment: TY but how to load the js file here?

Comment: @user1743942: You already loaded the JavaScript here: `<script src="http://www.domain.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`  When that tag is parsed by the browser, the JavaScript it references is loaded and executed.  In your case, "executed" should mean to load a function into memory and attach that function to the click event of what you want to click.

Comment: @user1743942 If you want to load some JS file I've edited my post so check it out. your JS file will load only after user presses hyperlink with id 'test'

Comment: OK so i've got `<script src="http://www.site.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a id='test' href="#">text</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#test').live('click', function() 
{
     $.getScript('http://www.site.com/file.js', function() {
alert('Load was performed.');
     });

}); 

});
</script>

` but it isnt working

Comment: I've edited my post, now it has all needed tags. All you need to add there, change `your_script_file.js` so it will call your JS file. If it is in the same folder then just write there your file_name.js without http or wwww. like this `$.getScript('file.js', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wan to execute some JavaScript when the user clicks on some text.

Wrap the JS in a function, in my example I will call it `doSomething()`.
JS:

```
function doSomething() {
    // your JS (this can be in another file too)
}
```

HTML:

```
<span onclick="doSomething()">text</span>
```

OR:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething">text</a>
```

Comment: TY can you tell me how to easily load the external js file to this function. Must i use jQuery getScript ?

Comment: Nope, this function can be in the external file. Just include it with `<script src="yourScript.js" ...></script>`. @user1743942